# Diagonally dominant matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be diagonally dominant. Show that A is invertible using the Neumann Series.

I want to show that $A^{-1}$ exists, that is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (I-A)^n$ converges to $(I-(I-A))^{-1}=A^{-1}$. Now, the series converges if the spectral radius of $I-A$ is strictly less than 1, which is equivalent to that of $A$ being strictly less than 2. However, I do not see how to show this property. I have managed to show for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$:

\begin{equation*}Ax = \lambda x, \text{ let } j \text{ be the index s.t } \lvert x_j \rvert \text{ is maximal, then:} \lvert \lambda - a_{jj} \rvert \leq \sum_{i=0, i \neq j}^n \lvert a_{ij} \rvert\end{equation*}

Comment: "Now, the series converges if the spectral radius of − is strictly less than 1, which is equivalent to that of  being strictly less than 2 " -- this isn't true; consider $A=-I$ which is a diagonally dominant matrix with spectral radius strictly less than 2.